# Having access to select value from a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question is really noob but i don't have a lot of knowledge in javascript.
I have a php/js project with tables.

When i click on a table row, i have a event and in this event i would like to able to get access from a value.

I'm trying to get it using GetElementbyId but it doesn't work.

I think it's related to the id. My id is "ssp_typo". I tried severals possibility but i don't get the value :

[image]

I just want to get the value of the 5th element ( it has the ssp_typo id).

I tried a getElementById("ssp_typo") and getElementById("#ssp_typo") whitout luck.

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `getElementById("ssp_typo")` should work. What is the error?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('ssp_typo')` instead. Elements don't have the `getElementById` method but the `document` object does.

Comment: If you have only one id="ssp_typo" `document.getElementById("ssp_typo").value`

Comment: Saddly all these are including in a tab with multiples rows so i cannot get it using document.getElementById. So my question is how to get value of the "ssp_typo" in this "element" ?

Comment: I solved it : I was getting the wrong element when i was getting the TableProject element !